# how to prevent submitting some html input elements to server?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an html form that has some input elements, and I have a select element that has to be inside form element because of webpage look. My problem is that "select" dropDown list is only does client side editing of my textarea and I don't want it to be sent to server. How should I prevent it? 

 Using ASP.net MVC 4.

Comment: Is it really a problem that its sent to the server. If its not bound to a model property its going to be ignored anyway or you could use the `[Bind(Exclude..` attribute. Another option is to handle the submit button and disable the control before submitting (disabled controls are not posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be sent to the server if it has no `name` attribute. Try removing that.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, some people believes that it's still being send with null string for name. is that true?

Comment: I just tested this with [a bit of PHP](https://gist.github.com/Scimonster/49facf61de3e6a8b90a0), and it doesn't seem so. And of course, it's the browser that determines what gets sent, not the server.